# How can I get A$B$C$D or A%B%C%D from A$$$B$$$$$$C$$$$$$$$$D string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How do I get `A$B$C$D` or `A%B%C%D` from `A$$$B$$$$$$C$$$$$$$$$D` string in SQL Server?

Comment: `REPLACE( col, '$$', '$')`

Comment: Just run set @data = replace(@data, '$$', '$') until the length of the string doesn't change?

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @col VARCHAR(MAX) = 'A$$$B$$$$$$C$$$$$$$$$D'

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@col, '$', '{}'), '}{', ''), '{}', '$')
```

Comment: @MaheshPanchala Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.